# Is it a rule that all the input parameters should be null checked for public API's?

Tags: java, android, api, native

I have an API which is exposed to multiple users.

Is it a rule that I should check all the input parameters for `null` in my API?

Or is it the developer's responsibility to not to send `null` objects?

Or the API designer's responsibility is just to mention in the Java doc not to send `null` objects ?

What is the mandate for this?

Comment: There is no mandate. Design by contract exists for a reason. And don't spam tags.

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules - just document what the API needs/expects.

Comment: If you tell the user not to give you a null pointer then it's not your responsibility but theirs.

Comment: quoting Scott Meyers : Make your interfaces(API) easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly.

Comment: There are numerous (and conflicting) guidelines on API design. Search and read and make up your own opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding returning null

The fact-based answer is: avoid returning null where possible!

Java8 introduced [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html); other strategies are to return an empty collection for example (instead of a null collection).

**Returning** null is always the first step towards a NullPointerException - thus you want to avoid it. But of course, that doesn't come to free; sometimes you need a lot of thinking to find a good solution.

### Regarding null input parameters

Checking inputs ... that is really up to you respectively the requirements that your users express.

My "personal" take here: use `Objects.requireNonNull()` and **immediately** check all incoming parameters when they are supposed to be non-null. And clearly document that in your javadoc:

```
@throws NullPointerException if any of the provided arguments is null
```

You see, when your code will call methods on any of the parameters, code will throw anyway. So it is **better** to check upfront - instead of having your code do (a lot of) things, before throwing up.

In other words: make sure your code "fails" as fast as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Getting **null** value is not because of bad programming habits only, It's also can possible due to slow network issue or dependent methods communications.

So, in between these all scenarios, we can't say that particular API  will not get null value anymore.

That's why we need to check for the null value first and also prevent the application instead of the error generated due to this and save the path to work.